# comparing length of the sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality

I have a triangle, with $\alpha\ge90^\circ$ (see figure). Now for an application I want to get a lower bound for $f+h-g$ (i.e the cost of the "detour" over $A$). But I don't know if there is a meaningful bound depending only on $f$ and $h$.

with the Law of cosines I get:

$f+h-g=f+h-\sqrt{f^2+h^2-2fh \cos{\alpha}}\\$

now I know $\alpha\ge90^\circ$ therefore I can't just throw away the $-2fh \cos{\alpha}$  and I have no clue how to go on.
Are there some other identities I could use or a specific inequality?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly:

$$f+h-g = f+h-\sqrt{f^2+h^2-2fh\cos\alpha}$$

OTOH, that doesn't help you to get a **lower** bound on the detour cost, $\alpha \ge 90^\circ$ means $\cos\alpha \le 0$, so we have

$$f+h-g = f+h-\sqrt{f^2+h^2-2fh\cos\alpha} \le f+h-\sqrt{f^2+h^2}$$

as an **upper** bound. It can't be made any better, as $\alpha=90^\circ$ is possible and $C$ could be on that line indicated in the picture.

A trivial lower bound would be

$$f+h-g \ge 0$$

by the triangle inequality, and that is also sharp: Nothing I see prevents $\alpha=180^\circ$ and thus the detour from $B$ to $C$ via $A$ is no detour at all, $A$ is on the way!

Comment: Thanks. 
I changed it in the Post